# Is it possible to open Google Chrome as a ConEmu/Cmder tab?

Tags: google-chrome, conemu, cmder

I can do this for Visual Studio Code by defining a new task in Cmder: `code -new_console`, and the editor opens as a new tab. However, doing the same for Chrome opens a new browser window instead of a tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this `> -cur_console:d:C:\Users\User "chrome.exe" --windowid !ConEmuBackHWND!`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still opens a new window for me. Does it work for you?